# ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario ingrese texto sin que se corte cuando oprime el espacio?

Tags: c++, string

En mi programa quisiera hacer que el usuario escriba una oración pequeña pero no logro conseguir que la escriba con espacios

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Te invito a que leas esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así que edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has hecho, luego detalla la duda e inquietud que tengas sobre dicho código.

Comment: ¿y tu programa? ¿adivinamos cómo lo estás haciendo?

Comment: ¿Que quieres prohibir que el usuario use espacio?

Comment: tal vez un `string variable; std::getline(cin,variable);` pueda servirte, poniendo `#include<string>` en el encabezado, pero la verdad no estas siendo específico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que quieres es almacenar toda una línea dentro de una variable del tipo `string`, debes usar la función `getline` de la librería `string`, un ejemplo simple sería:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;

int main() {
    cout << "Ingrese una oración:" << endl;
    string var;
    getline(cin, var);//atrapará todo lo que escribes en una línea incluido espacios
    cout << var << endl;//para que verifiques lo anterior
}
```